# Modeling objects with no id in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am building a dashboard application for an accounting department.

The user will select a month, and see all the companies that meet certain criteria in that month. The routes will be

```
/:month_id                         a summary page
/:month_id/companies               more details about each company
/:month_id/companies/:company_id   all details about a single company
```

Ideally I'd have a `month` model which `hasMany` `company` models. The only problem is, companies will show up in multiple months.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this mean that if a company is already in the store, when a new month is requested, it will take that company's data from the store instead of from the server? The data will be different for each month, so this wouldn't work for me.

I suppose in this application each company's id is really their normal, integer id plus the selected month. So one way around this would be to give each company an id like `'15-Mar-2013'`.

Alternatively, I could just pass each month's `companies` data through raw and do transformations on the plain array. The problem with this, though, is that I'll have to calculate aggregates on companies (in addition to the entire month), and it would be very nice to keep those two things separate. If I had a completely separate Company model, I could just go to town within the model:

```
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
    month: DS.belongsTo('App.Month'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    contracts: DS.hasMany('App.Contract'),

    totalRevenue: function() {
        return this.get('contracts')
            .filterProperty('type', 'newSetup')
            .getEach('feeChange').reduce(function(accum, item) {
                return accum + item;
            }, 0);
    }.property('contracts.@each.feeChange'),

    ...additional aggregation functions
});
```

What do you think?

Comment: If the data for the company is different every month then the record is not a company. It's a `CompanyReport` or something.

Comment: Agreed, but still - how to solve the problem? Assign an arbitrary id to the `CompanyReport`? The `CompanyReport` is essentially a filtered snapshot of some set of server data.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense to me that months own companies, which is what your `month[1]->[N]company` relationship indicates.

What you want to say is that you're looking for all companies that have certain criteria that occur within a month. The month chosen is just part of the search criteria.

Comment: Agreed but it's more of a `MonthlyReport`, and to me that does make sense. In that case, how to solve the problem?

Comment: If you looking for a bookmarkable report, than I would probably do something like "/companies/reports/:reportName/:yyyy/:mm" to identify the specific report.  Or "/reports/periodic/:yyyy/:mm/:reportName"  or "/reports/monthly/:yyyy/:mm/:name'

Comment: I'm using :month-id as :yyyy/:mm (it's going to be something like `Jan-2013`). So I still don't know how to solve the problem.